# Как распознать ссылочную переменную?

Tags: c#

Как в программе на языке C# распознать ссылочную переменную без ключевого слова ref?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переменная ссылочного типа всегда имеет ссылочный тип данных. В C# такими типами являются классы, интерфейсы и делегаты.

Comment: тогда как распознать ссылочную переменную внутри класса?

Comment: @MartinEden если она имеет ссылочный тип, следовательно это ссылка. Всегда. И не важно где она расположена.

Comment: например, public Node Next, имеет ссылочный тип? т.е. переменная Next каким типом обладает?

Comment: @MartinEden запись public Node Next означает, что это публичная переменная, которая может хранить в себе ссылку на объект класса Node (ссылочная переменная).

Comment: спасибо, и ещё, такая структура соблюдается для всех ссылочных переменных?

Comment: @MartinEden Структура может различаться. К примеру, если это поле класса, то не всегда может указываться модификатор доступа (в вашем примере - public). Переменные без модификатора доступа по умолчанию являются private (зыкрытыми).

Comment: например, есть у нас переменные ссылочного типа Next и Tail, относящиеся к одному классу, тогда что значит следующее выражение: Tail.Next = p, где p - новый объект, принадлежащий тому же классу, что и Tail и Next?

Comment: @MartinEden запись Tail.Next в вашем случае невозможна. Через точку можно обращаться только к начинке вашего объекта Tail (события, публичные методы, публичные поля).

Comment: @MartinEden я бы Вам посоветовал почитать книгу по основам С# и ООП, либо посмотрите видеуроки C# базовый курс. Если вы новичок - по комментариям на этом форуме Вам трудно будет обучиться.

Comment: но работает, я пытаюсь сделать динамический список

Comment: @MartinEden ну так вы бы сказали, что Next объявлен внутри Tail, я ведь не провидец. Tail.Next= P означает, что полю класса Tail (полю Next) присвоена ссылка на новый объект P